# One line toasting error in java Incompatible types

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

When I want to do a one line toast in Java I get this error message:

```
JavaTester.java:34: incompatible types
found   : void
required: android.widget.Toast
Toast newToast = Toast.makeText(this, "This is a one liner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
1 error
```

Has anyone got any idea what I can do to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to declare the `Toast` object

```
Toast.makeText(this, "This is a one liner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Just like that you'll have the `Toast` shown

Or if you need to custom your toast then remove the call to ´show()´

```
Toast newToast = Toast.makeText(this, "This is a one liner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//Do stuff here
newToast.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the `.show()` method, which has a `void` return type. Either don't try to use the result:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "This is a one liner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or use two statements:

```
Toast newToast = Toast.makeText(this, "This is a one liner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
newToast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Toast toast is an object instance of Toast, and Toast.makeText() is a static reference.  Remove Toast toast = and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

No need for assignment into newToast since show() returns void.